# Insert into database issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

This thing is really weird for me i create an app, on my first view (login view) i enter email id and password and then verify this from database and if it ok then move to new view and in that view i fill some fields and then enter that data into database but it dnt enter data into my database .this verification of login view

```
-(NSInteger)verifyLoginEmail:(NSString *)email Password:(NSString *)password
{
       NSInteger a=1;
        const char *selectQuery="SELECT * FROM CreateProfile where email=? AND password=?";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_open([destPath UTF8String],&studentDB)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, sid);

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(studentDB,selectQuery, -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
            { 
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
                {

                    return a;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return 2;
                }

            }
                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
            sqlite3_close(studentDB);


        return 0;
}
```

and this code is for insert data from new view

```
-(void)insertName:(NSString *)name Email:(NSString *)email Password:(NSString *)password Pic:(NSString *)pic;
{
    const char *insertQuery="insert into CreateProfile (name,email,pic,password) values (?,?,?,?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_open([destPath UTF8String],&studentDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(studentDB, insertQuery, -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        { 
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [pic UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);  
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT); 
            //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, rollno);


        }
        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE){
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Profile Created" message:@"Your profile successfully added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(studentDB);

    }
```

when i directly go to view from changing view from main window i can enter fields into database but i cant enter into database when i login and then move to new view

Comment: Insert `NSLog` statements into your code and check the results of your sqlite functions.

Comment: You also might consider using Gus Mueller's FMDB (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a nice Obj-C wrapper around sqlite.

Comment: if it is image than change datatype. image datatype in sqlite is BLOB

Comment: Could you show us the value of 'destPath', please?

Comment: check destPath and database name its is case sensitivity

Comment: you can check :if you have Error in dataBase use this code in both Function:-

    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(destPath));

Answer (score 0):

In your **(NSInteger)verifyLoginEmail:(NSString *)email Password:(NSString *)password** funcation

You have written

```
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

replace those two lines with lines shown below

```
   sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 0, [email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

In Select Query the binding starts from 0 . and In insert statements the binding starts from 1.

and Instead of returning   **a** , return some integer value like  **1** , because your method's return type is NSInteger.

Hope it will work.